# How do I call a retrieve method in a BST

Tags: java, methods, tree

So I'm making a binary search tree and one of the methods I need to make is a retrieve method which finds a certain value and returns it. Here's the method (I haven't tested it yet so I'm not sure if it's right)

```
protected TreeNode retrieveItem(TreeNode r, String word) {
    if (r == null){
        return null;
    }
    if (word.compareTo(r.item.getWord()) < 0){
        return retrieveItem(r.left, word);
    } else if (word.compareTo(r.item.getWord()) > 0 ){
        return retrieveItem(r.right, word);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Because this is a protected method, it needs to be called from a public method. Usually to call these methods I would do something like

```
public void delete(String word) {
    root = deleteItem(root, word);
}
```

Which calls a delete method using root (which is already declared) and word. The problem with calling the retrieve method is that the method looks like this

```
public WordRefs retrieve(String word) {
    return null;
}
```

It says return null because I don't know what the return value is supposed to be and I'm not sure what I have to do to call it. So how do I call this method?

Here's the WordRefs class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class WordRefs {
    private String word;
    private LinkedList<Integer> lineNumbers;


    public WordRefs(String word) {
        this.word = word;
        lineNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
    }


    public void addLine(int lineNumber) {
        lineNumbers.add(lineNumber);
    }


    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }


    public LinkedList<Integer> getLineNumbers() {
        return lineNumbers;
    }


    public String toString() {
        String result = word + ":";

        for (Integer ii : lineNumbers) {
            result += " " + ii;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `retrieveItem()` returns a `TreeNode`, shouldn't `retrieve()` return a `TreeNode` also? Returning the same `word` would make no sense, and returning a `boolean` indicating if `word` was found would only make sense if it was a `contains()` like method.

Comment: It's actually supposed to return a WordRefs not a TreeNode however would posting the entire class help figure things out?

Answer (score 0):

Given the `WordRefs` class, I think something like this should work:

```
public WordRefs retrieve(String word) {
    TreeNode node = retrieveItem(root, word);
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return new WordRefs(node.item.word);
    }
}
```

If `node.item` contains any information about `lineNumber` you can add that before returning the `WordRefs` object.

Comment: One problem with that code. Word only has private access in the WordRefs class however I just fixed it by adding the getWord() method to find the word. I haven't tested it yet but I assume getWord() should work.